# Python debugger detaches itself from code after importing a module

Tags: python, linux, debugging, intellij-idea

Whenever trying to debug a piece of code executed after dynamic module import is performed, the debugger detaches itself from the code.
I can debug code up to line below, stepping over this line causes debugger to detach itself.

This occurs when using imp library to import a module.

```py
imp.load_source(module_name, path_to_file)
```

The reason i need this code to execute is to get a list of classes and test methods to pass them over to unittest.

If i'll use unittest loader discover to get a list of tests I get the same results i.e. debugger detaches itself.

This issue appeared only after dev environment was upgraded to Python 2.7.13 from 2.7.8

Comment: Have you tried PyCharm? Normally it works better than Intellij IDEA with Python plugin.

Comment: I haven't no - intellij-idea is used company-wide.